# How to merge 10 collections (with the same structure) into a single collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 10 collections (with the names user_01, user_02, ... user_10). These 10 collections all have the same structure (I import from CSV file into MongoDB). Because the data of each CSV file is too big I have to split into 10 different files (data_01.csv, data_02.csv, ... data_10.csv) when importing into MongoDB (I put in 10 different collections as above, not a single collection).

But now I need to merge these 10 collections into a single collection called "user" to query data. Is there any way to migrate data from these 10 collections into a single collection called "user"?

The structure of each collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6119cac0fe31d614997b07f0"),
    "name": "Robert"
    "address" : "36 rue Nationale, Paris, France",
    "sex" : "female",
    "age" : 45,
    "account_activated_date" : 19990101
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.user_01.aggregate([
{
    '$unionWith': {
      'coll': 'user_02'
    }
},
{
    '$unionWith': {
      'coll': 'user_03'
    }
},
.
.
.
{
    '$unionWith': {
      'coll': 'user_10'
    }
},
{
    '$out': 'users' //name of new collection
  }
])
```

use `unionWith` to add all data from another collection to current collection ddo it for all collection and use `out` to add to new collection